# Keywords search with multiple terms

Tags: solr, full-text-search, sunspot-rails, keyword-search

I would like to write something like this:

```
 keywords ['apple', 'peach'], :fields => [:fruits]
```

If I have two different instances where one has 'apple' and the other has 'peach', I want both of them to be returned in results.

I have tried syntax, that I have mentioned above, but I only get a match for first term('apple').

Does sunspot even supports this? I was not able to find that it does which does not mean that I haven't missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have two instances of your model, one with `name` apple, second one with `name` equal peach and third one with name 'apple peach'. If you want to get either one of them you should do something similar to the following:

```
Product.search do
  minimum_match 1
  keywords 'apple peach' # btw, fulltext is an alias to keywords
end
```

Now you will get all three results (at least you should get), crucial part is `minimum_match`, without that Sunspot will use its defaults setting which is to return only 'full' matches (all phrases found).

Comment: That's it! It works perfectly! Thank you so much! 
I have used this syntax thought 
     keywords('apple peach'){minimum_match}